# Android ExoPlayer issue

Tags: android, exoplayer

While I'm loading content type "audio/aacp" stream using Android ExoPlayer, having an exception <'OMX.qcom.audio.decoder.aac' already exists, ignoring this one.>. But my player is working after having this exception. How to handle this issue and why it's happening.

**Sample Code**

```
SampleSource s = new DefaultSampleSource(new FrameworkSampleExtractor(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(path), null), 2)

ExoPlayer player = ExoPlayer.Factory.newInstance(1);

MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer audioRenderer = new MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer(s);
player.prepare(audioRenderer);

player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen that Android framework caches the OMX codec that is loaded in memory and re-uses it if another application wants to instantiate it again. May be you are seeing that log here. I don't think its throws an exception though.